# How To Analyze Time-Series Data And Remove "Duplicate" Records

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series

I have a large set of data (~2M rows) that describes vehicle data as they move around a large parking complex. That is, each vehicle gets scanned as it passes through multiple "zones" in the structure. It looks something like this:

```
+--------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
|   id   | zone_camera_id |  plate   |      timestamp      |
+--------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
| 453445 | Z05-C01        | AAAABBBB | 2020-06-25 08:02:23 |
| 453446 | Z05-C02        | AAAABBBB | 2020-06-25 08:04:55 |
| 453447 | Z03-C01        | CCCCDDDD | 2020-06-25 08:05:19 |
| 453448 | Z02-C02        | AAAABBBB | 2020-06-25 08:05:23 |
| 453449 | Z07-C03        | CCCCDDDD | 2020-06-25 08:09:08 |
| 453450 | Z07-C04        | CCCCDDDD | 2020-06-25 08:10:01 |
| 453451 | Z04-C04        | AAAABBBB | 2020-06-25 08:11:44 |
| 453452 | Z04-C01        | AAAABBBB | 2020-06-25 08:11:59 |
| 453453 | Z04-C03        | AAAABBBB | 2020-06-25 08:12:06 |
| 453454 | Z05-C03        | AAAABBBB | 2020-06-25 08:13:00 |
+--------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
```

`camera_id` breaks down like this: `<Zone ID>-<Camera ID>`, and `<Camera ID>` is generally irrelevant; a vehicle being detected by `Z05-C01` is equivalent the same vehicle being detected by `Z05-C04`.

I can quickly `GROUP BY` the `zone_camera_id` using `LEFT()`, like this:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS scan_count,
       LEFT(zone_camera_id, 3) AS zone
FROM   vehicle_scans
WHERE  plate = 'AAAABBBB'
GROUP  BY LEFT(zone_camera_id, 3)
```

And I see:

```
+------------+------+
| scan_count | zone |
+------------+------+
| Z05        |    3 |
| Z02        |    1 |
| Z04        |    3 |
+------------+------+
```

This is great information, however it does not offer any insight into the "path" that the driver took. This query has no idea of time sequencing, such that if a driver starts in `Z02`, goes to `Z05`, and *comes back to * `Z02`, those `Z02` scans will be lumped-in together.

What I am looking to do is remove the "duplicate" scans, where a driver got scanned multiple times in the same zone in a row (didn't leave the zone, as in `ID=453445,453446` but NOT `ID=453454` when the driver returned) but never left the zone. Basically, I want to know when a driver entered a zone and exited a zone, *without visiting a different zone during that time period*.

I am looking to determine how much time each vehicle spent in each zone continuously, even if they return to that zone at a later time, something like this:

```
+---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| zone_id | scan_count |     enter_time      |      exit_time      |
+---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Z05     |          2 | 2020-06-25 08:02:23 | 2020-06-25 08:04:55 |
| Z02     |          1 | 2020-06-25 08:05:23 | 2020-06-25 08:05:23 |
| Z04     |          3 | 2020-06-25 08:11:44 | 2020-06-25 08:12:06 |
| Z05     |          1 | 2020-06-25 08:13:00 | 2020-06-25 08:13:00 |
+---------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

*`Z05` appears twice, because they visited the zone twice, with two other zone-visits in between.*

This is what I have tried, using `Min()` and `Max()`:

```
SELECT Count(*)                 AS scan_count,
       LEFT(camera_zone_id, 3)  AS zone_id,
       Min(timestamp)           AS enter_time,
       Max(timestamp)           AS exit_time
FROM   vehicle_scans
WHERE  plate = 'AAAABBBB'
GROUP  BY LEFT(camera_zone_id, 3)
ORDER  BY enter_time
```

This is great information, and it matches the structure of my desired output, however the `Min()` and `Max()` values reflect the absolute minimum and maximum timestamps for scans within that zone, as opposed to the minimum and maximum timestamps for scan sequences in singular zones. In cases above like with `AAAABBBB`, the vehicle begins in `Z05`, visits two more zones, and then returns to `Z05`. The above query uses the first `Z05` scan and the very-last `Z05` scan, even though there were two more zones visited (`Z02` and `Z04`) in between. I am looking for each uninterrupted "visit" to a zone in its own row, removing "duplicate" scans while they continue to get scanned in `LEFT(camera_zone_id, 3)`.

Is there a SQL-based method to group these rows in uninterrupted sequences?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a gap-and-islands problem -- but you need to consolidate this by the plate.

Difference of row numbers is handy:

```
select plate, left(camera_zone_id, 3), min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select vs.*,
              row_number() over (partition by plate, left(camera_zone_id, 3) order by timestamp) as seqnum_pc,
              row_number() over (partition by plate order by timestamp) as seqnum_p
      from vehicle_scans vs
     ) vs
group by plate, (seqnum_pc - seqnum_p)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you have made me look very smart!!